# Change order of items (shuffle) in .txt file NodeJS

Tags: node.js, fs

How can I change order of items that are in .txt file in NodeJS using fs?
The items are one item = one line in .txt file.

I want to randomize/shuffle it and write shuffled version to the .txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a file with content as follows

```
first line
second
...
```

you can try something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
    return array;
}

const array = fs.readFileSync('file.txt').toString().split("\n");

fs.writeFileSync('file.txt', shuffleArray(array).join('\n'));
```